# VBScript modify a value in a XML file

Tags: xml, vbscript

I'm learning VBScript and I am trying to modify values on a xml file using vbscript but I always get an error with the variable "colNode":

> Microsoft VBScript Runtime Error: This object does not support this
> property or method: 'colNode.Text

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Text Name="Text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </Text>
    <Text Name="Text2">Aliquam mattis quam lorem, ut sollicitudin dolor dignissim sed. </Text>
    <Text Name="Text3">Fusce cursus tellus eu consectetur rutrum.</Text>
</Configuration>
```

And here is my VBScript code:

```
    Set xmlDoc = _
    CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

    xmlDoc.Async = "False"
    xmlDoc.Load(".\message.xml")

    
    Set colNode=xmlDoc.selectNodes _
  ("//Configuration/Text[@Name='Text2']")

    
    colNode.Text = "It's a test!"  
    xmlDoc.Save "C:\Scripts\Audits.xml"
```

Comment: Try `Set colNode=xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Configuration/Text[@Name='Text2']")`

Comment: Try it and get the following error message: `Required object: 'colNode`

Comment: Same error message `Required object: 'colNode(...)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectNodes` method returns a collection of nodes (in this case a collection of just one) and if you want to use that, you need to iterate through that collection in order to change the text in every node in the collection:

```
Set colNode=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Configuration/Text[@Name='Text2']")
For Each node In colNode
    node.Text = "It's a test!"
Next
```

In your example however, you are seeking to change the text in only one specific node, so for that you ca use the `SelectSingleNode` method:

```
Set colNode=xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Configuration/Text[@Name='Text2']")
colNode.Text = "It's a test!"
```

Comment: I got the following error message: `Required object: 'colNode'`

Comment: @Noemie That's because your XPath query selects nothing, so `colNode` will not be set properly. (In other words, the sample XML from your question is different from your real XML.)

Comment: I try with "SelectSingleNode" (uppercase S) and it works

Comment: @Noemie If I had to guess, your real XML is in a namespace (`xmlns="..."`) and you edited that out because you thought it was not important.